# why checkbox text is not appearing through android:text, is there any reason?

Tags: android, checkbox

Checkbox text is not displaying through android:text.Tried by changing text color but the result is same. why this happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ll_parent_adapter"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/resudlt_cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/llCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxMarkAsComplete"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Mark as complete"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorVendorCheckBox"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

complete xml is given above as per request.

Comment: can you post a complete xml?

Comment: post edited with complete xml @John Joe

Comment: make sure color of text is not matching the background.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `layout_width` to fix value of `30dp`. Try setting checkbox width to `wrap_content.`